# Difference between Gowin FIFO and FIFO HS IP

Tags: fpga, fifo, gowin

**The question:** what are the differences between the two Gowin's IP modules: [FIFO](https://cdn.gowinsemi.com.cn/IPUG105E.pdf) and [FIFO HS](https://cdn.gowinsemi.com.cn/IPUG760E.pdf)?

I can only assume, that HS stands for "high speed", hence it should be preferred over non-HS version if available. But this is just a speculation.

They have identical IP Customization interfaces and almost identical User Guides. The only noted differences are in FPGA family accessibility and estimates in Maximum Frequency and Resource Utilization section.

Does anybody know?

Comment: @DaveTweed That is not true. Both HS and regular FIFO have syncronous SC (same read and write clock) and asynchronous (separate read and write clks) configurations: FIFO IP, FIFO SC IP, FIFO HS IP, FIFO SC HS IP.

Comment: Since I don't have access to the user manuals, all I could do was make inferences from the website descriptions. Sorry!

Comment: @DaveTweed No problem! It was just a clarification on the matter. I was hoping that someone has already dealt with those IP.